Upper bound of $2\vert\cos{\frac{x+y}2}\sin{\frac{x-y}2}\vert$
We have $2\left|\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\right|$
As $\left|\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\right|\leq 1$
$\left|\sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\right|\leq 1$
Is it true? that
$2\left|\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\right|\leq 2$

Yes, this is true.

Can we find any other Upper bound less than 2?

No, this is sharp. Try $y = -\tfrac{\pi}{2}$ and $x = \tfrac{\pi}{2}$

you're essentially expanding $|\sin x - \sin y|$. Of course it's max value should be 2 when $x=\frac{π}{2},y=\frac{-π}{2}$

Use the identity,
$\sin x-\sin y=2\cos{\frac{x+y}2}\sin{\frac{x-y}2}$
So your equation changes to
$\vert\sin x-\sin y\vert\le2$
at $x=\frac{(4n+1)\pi}2$ and $y=\frac{(4n-1)\pi}2$ where $n\in I$
So yes it is true.
